# Why my eclipse [on vista] shows incorrect file modification timestamp?

Tags: eclipse, windows-vista, timestamp

When I right-click on a recently modified file (like a jar generated by Java Builder) and view the file properties, the modification timestamp is always off by 2.5 hrs. Windows explorer, on the other hand, is showing correct timestamp.

I suspect that their some time zone setting in eclipse somewhere that is used in translating the file system time.

I am running Ganymede on Vista with Sun JDK 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse support [**jar signing**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing), it may be possible it does display the timestamp stored in the signature as opposed to the one associated with the file. Maybe that timestamp is computed on a GMT-base as opposed to a local-time base.

> Starting in J2SE 5.0, jarsigner can generate signatures that include a timestamp, thus enabling systems/deployer (including Java Plug-in) to check whether the JAR file was signed while the signing certificate was still valid

Are your jar signed ? What does the associated MANIFEST include ?
Is 2.5h consistent with a timeshift between GMT and your zone ?

Comment: I checked and the problem appears on source (*.java) as well. Time +2.5hrs doesn't seems to be consistent. This morning, I am seeing -10.5 hrs (after I turned on my notebook that I hibernated last night).

Comment: Very strange... do you see the same thing with Galileo (3.5RC2) ?